# Merge params in rewrite paths

Tags: url-rewriting, couchdb

Can I merge params as one in rewrite handlers or VHOST ?

In example:

```
{
       "from": "/:db/:year/:doc",
       "to": "../../../:db%2F:year/:doc",
       "method": "GET"

   }
```

I have database named mydb/2015. In URL slash '/' will be URL-encoded to %2F. I would like to have pretty URL and query:

```
/mydb%2F2015/myDocId
```

change to

```
/mydb/2015/myDocId
```

DocId could have chars which should be URL-encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not permitted:

> You can have / as part of the document ID but if you refer to a
>   document in a URL you must always encode it as %2F. One special case
>   is _design/ documents, those accept either / or %2F for the / after
>   _design, although / is preferred and %2F is still needed for the rest of the DocID.

[Prooflink](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Documents)